# Proving that this infinite product is convergent

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product

This question was asked in my assignment in number theory and I could not prove it.

> Question : Define the  multiplicative function w(n) such that $w(p^k) =0$ for $k\geq 2$ and w(p)= { $\frac{p} { f(p)} $ if $p\in P$, 0 if $p\notin P$}. Suppose that w(n) satisfies $ \sum_{p\leq z} \frac{w(p) log(p)} {p} = Klog z+O(1)$ where $K \geq 0$. Then show that $\prod_{p\leq z} (1- \frac{w(p)} {p}) \sim c_w \frac{e^{-\gamma K} } { (logz)^
> K}$ where $c_w = \prod_{p} (1- \frac{w(p)} {p} ) ( 1- 1/p)^{-K}$ is a convergent product and $\gamma $ is a constant.

Attempt:  By Merten's theorem , $ \prod_{p \leq z}( 1-1/p)^{K} \sim \frac {e^{-\gamma K}} { (log z)^K}$.

I can write $\prod_{p\leq z} (1- \frac{w(p) }{p}) $ as equal to  $\prod_{ p\leq z} ( 1-1/p)^K (1-1/p)^{-K} ( 1- w(p)/p)$

But I don't have much ideas on how to proceed from here. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

By partial summation, one can deduce the existence of a constant $C_0$ such that

$$
\sum_{p\le z}{w(p)\over p}=K\log\log z+C_0+O\left(1\over\log z\right)
$$

As $t\to0^+$, we know $-\log(1-t)=t+O(t^2)$, so we also know that there exists another constant $C_1$ such that

$$
-\sum_{p\le z}\log\left(1-{w(p)\over p}\right)=K\log\log z+C_1+O\left(1\over\log z\right)
$$

Exponentiating both side gives

$$
\prod_{p\le z}\left(1-{w(p)\over p}\right)={e^{-C_1}\over\log^Kz}\left\{1+O\left(1\over\log z\right)\right\}
$$

Juxtaposing this asymptotic formula with Mertens' theorem will yield what you expect.

Comment: In the 4th line of your answer can  you please elaborate on how you simplified the term $O( \sum_{p\leq z} \frac{ w^{p}}  { p^2}$ which will appear on the RHS.

Comment: Applying partial summation to $\sum_{a<p\le b}{w(p)\over p^2}$ can show that this sum is convergent.

Comment: Can you please help with an inequality in this question which I have asked in comments but no one is replying to :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452404/how-to-estimate-sz-in-arithmetic-large-sieve?