# How to estimate S(z) in Arithmetic Large Sieve

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

This question is part of a proof in  course in Sieve Theory(  [http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html), precisely lecture 11 and 14)and I am not able to prove this particular statement. I have thought about it enough but couldn't make progress so I am posting it.

Let $S(z) =  \sum_{n\leq z , n |P(z)} \frac{\mu^2(n)} { (\mu * f)(n)}$. Define the multiplicative function  w(n) such that $w(p^k) =0 $ for $k\geq 2$ and w(p)= { p/ f(p) if $p \in P$ , 0 if $p \notin P$} . I have proved that $S(z) =  \sum_{ d \leq z}  \frac { w(d) } { d \prod_{p | d} ( 1- w(p) /p)}$.

I am struck on the an assertion of proof of Linnik's theorem( on page 3 of lecture 14):  For square frees $n = p_1 ...p_n$, $w(n) = w(p_1) ...w(p_n)$. A={1,...,N} , P = { $p \leq N^{1/2} : (n/p) =1 $for all $n \leq N^{\epsilon}$}  and $\Omega_p = ${  h ( mod p) : (h/p) =-1}. w(p) = #$\Omega_p = (p-1)/2$, p>2.

> Prove that $S(z) \geq \sum_{p\leq z} w(p)/p  = 1/2 \sum_{p \in P} (1- 1/p)$.

Kindly help me with this!

Comment: Isn't this obvious? The sum defining $S(z)$ is over all $d \le z$, so it is lower bounded by the sum over $p \le z$ (everything is non-negative). Also, $\prod_{p \mid d} (1-w(p)/p)$ is always less than $1$, so we can rid of it when lower bounding.

Comment: @mathworker21 Ya, but how to deduce that $\sum_{p\leq z} w(p)/p  = 1/2 \sum_{p \in P} (1- 1/p)$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Can you please reply?

Comment: it's not something you *deduce* from the inequality. It's just something else you need to prove. Have you tried proving it (directly)? I don't even know if it's true. If you still can't figure it out, please redefine everything and only what's needed. I'm not sure what $z$ is...